# PHP - Email notification CRON

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to run a CRON once a day to notify my users when new content is uploaded.
In the table `user` there's a column called `content_pref` with values that look like this: `5,8,3,9`.

Here's the structure of my `upload_log`

```
+----------------------------------------+
| id | content_id | date       | is_sent |
+----------------------------------------+
| 1  | 2          | 2014-04-09 | 1       |
| 3  | 6          | 2014-04-09 | 1       |
| 4  | 8          | 2014-04-10 | 0       |
| 5  | 9          | 2014-04-10 | 0       |
+----------------------------------------+
```

And the `user` table

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | username   | password    | email           | content_pref |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | bobby      | itsasecret! | bobby@email.com | 4,8,3,6      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically Bobby is interested in knowing when content 4,8,3,6 is updated.

In this case, Bobby will only get a notification for the `content_id` 8 since 9 is not in his preferences.

The question is how can I cross reference the `content_perf` with the `content_id` and make it return true?

Comment: 1. Don't store it as a CSV. Use a pivot table. 2. Join on that pivot table.

Comment: First you redesign your `user` table so it's properly normalized. You should NEVER store "csv" data in a single field, especially when you need to deal with the sub-data regularly.

Comment: @MarcB I wish it wasn't in this format. But it was already done by the previous programmer. What would be the best way to redo the table?

Comment: @ceejayoz Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Best way js to split that out into a properly normalized data structure. This is tricky to do entirely in MySQL, but if you have a scripting language, you can do it really easily.

Comment: @tadman I can either do it in PHP or export to Excel and do Text to Column. But after that, what do I do with it? I have over 100 choices.